# background image not working in CSS, I've tried changing file path and still doesn't work

Tags: css, background-image

```
#objective-image {
background-image: url(/resorces/img-locations-background.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

I have tried changing the image path and moving it around but when I open the html file on my web browser it shows not image and appears black.

Comment: Remove the `/` in front of *resources*.

Comment: We need more context. What does your file tree sort of look like? Whats your HTML? What are you applying this too? At this point, we can't help you any more than 'educated' guesses like misspelling the word resources, or starting with a leading slash (which means 'root', which might not be what you wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#objective-image {
background-image: url(../img-locations-background.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Fixed it by using ../ instead of /resources/